# Call Jquery Function with dynamic aspx repeater and dynamic id´s

Tags: jquery

I want to call a jquery Function while hovering a div in a dynamic repeater. On running i don´t know the ID´s in the Repeater.
i do it like this way, but won´t work:

http://jsfiddle.net/3mhAz/13/

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
function myFunc(myID) {
    $(this).AddClass("myborder");
}

function RemoveClass(myID) {
    $(this).RemoveClass("myborder");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "problem", as presented, is due to fiddle *not being used correctly* and some other typographical errors. (I've voted to close this question, because such a scenario is hard to reproduce.)

Here is a [corrected fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3mhAz/13/)<sup>1</sup>.

1. **Change the jsFiddle option "onLoad" to "No Wrap"** - look on the left panel in "Frameworks & Extensions".

   When using *onLoad* the JavaScript is executed *inside* a function and thus the functions are *local* to the onLoad function. As such, these functions are *not* available in the event callbacks within the fiddle. Alternatively, assign the function-objects to the window properties explicitly.
2. *Fix the typos* - JavaScript is *case sensitive*. There were several (e.g. `addClass` vs `AddClass`), all of which were reported in turn as errors in the error console. I also had to add the missing use of `onmouseout`.

Note that, in no case, an "ID" was used.

---

HTML:

```html
<div class="green" id="dew0do"
     onmouseover="myFunc(this);"
     onmouseout="RemoveClass(this);">test</div>
```

JavaScript:

```js
function myFunc(elm) {  /* but really choose better function names */
    $(elm).addClass("myborder");
}
function RemoveClass(elm) {
    $(elm).removeClass("myborder");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling

```
onmouseover="myFunc(this);
```

you should use

```
onmouseover="myFunc($(this).attr('id'));
```

and then, in the function, just try

```
function myFunc(myID) {
    $('#'+myID).AddClass("myborder");
}

function RemoveClass(myID) {
    $('#'+myid).RemoveClass("myborder");
}
```

Comment: Why not just `myFunc.call(this, event)`, then `function myFunc() { $(this).toggleClass("myborder") }`?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the DOM-hierarchy, you could just use (eg: div.container > div.list > ul > li ):

```
$(function(){
  $('div.container')
    .on("mouseover",  "div.list > ul > li", 
        function(){$(this).AddClass("myborder");} )
    .on("mouseout", "div.list > ul > li", 
        function(){$(this).RemoveClass("myborder");} );
}
```